# Does restoring an iPhone to factory settings before a restore from a backup produce a different result than just restoring from a backup?

Tags: iphone, backup, restore

Does restoring an iPhone to factory settings before a restore from a backup produce a different result than just restoring from a backup?

[Restore your iPhone, iPad, or iPod to factory settings](https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht201252)

[Restore your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch from a backup](https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht204184)

Comment: I always to the erase all settings and data first. Too many years in the IT biz, it only takes a few extra minutes, and while it may be unnecessary I prefer the belt *and* suspenders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No.**

Theres not much more to say. The end result will be the same: the device will be restored from a backup.